# Bluetooth Works In Any Linux Distro, but Not In Windows

Tags: linux, windows, audio, drivers, bluetooth

I have an Acer Aspire 5755G and Bluetooth works in any Linux distro, but not in Windows. I have tried downloading drivers from the Acer website, but neither of them worked, returning error:

```
Drivers can't find a Bluetooth device
```

Comment: https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/530364/missing-bluetooth-driver-in-windows-10-acer5755g  . This is not unusual for Win10 downgrades. However, there are several options that may resolve the problem. Let's try the easiest first.

 

Go to http://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/drivers. Enter your machine's SNID or Aspire 5755g and download either the Win7 atheros or broadcom bluetooth driver zipfiles. Unzip the files. And then run the installation file in "Win7 compatibility mode" .

Comment: So i can't run the win7 version in any compatibility mode it gives a error with broadcom and when i try to run atheros windows defender block it.I'll try to close the defender.                  https://prnt.sc/y5wo9n

Comment: Is this an older machine? There may not be a driver.

Comment: i bought it at 2012. Pc released at 2011 idk

Comment: https://prnt.sc/y5xg4x this is what atheros driver says. I disabled smartscreen

Comment: That is before Windows 10. Maybe contact Acer Support and see if they have an alternate or better driver.

Comment: Thanks anyways :(

Comment: So i downgraded to Windows 8 i can open the drivers but device still wont show up
Also broadcom driver wont install it says activate bluetooth with wireless switch i tried fn+f3 it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by holding <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> for three seconds.
F3 normally open and closes bt/wifi but i found out if you hold pressing it opens bt

Comment: What function does `F3` control? It likely turns BT on/off, which would be recommended to add to the answer, as the context matters.